# Routing issue with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC 3 and have an issue. Instead of giving mydomain/mydirectory/item like I expected I get this:

mydomain/mydirectory/list?animal=quack.

Here's the route in the global

```
//Default route mapping
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = @"[^\.]*", action = @"[^\.]*" }
);
```

Code showing how I'm building the link:

> ```
>    <div id="main-content" title="AnimalBox" style="float:none;">
>         <% Html.DataList(Model.PriceListAnimals).Columns(7).Item(item =>
>                 {
>                     item.Template(galleryImage =>  
>                     {%>
>                         <div style="margin-left:20px; line-height:150%;">
>                             <span><%= Html.ActionLink(galleryImage.AnimalName,"List",new { @animal = galleryImage.AnimalName }) %></span>
>                         </div>  
>                         <%  });
>                 }).Render(); %>
>     </div>
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be a good idea to share the code you use to create the link as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a route for special case routing like your instance.  Since you are passing 'animal' as a parameter, you should create a route to handle that instance.  In your global.aspx (above the default route), create something like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Animal", // A distinct Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{animal}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "MyDirectory", action = "List"}
);
```

This will define a route to the MyDirectory controller on the action list which has an animal parameter which is **NOT OPTIONAL**.  Defining routes is what enables you to generate clean URLs from the html helpers and other methods (redirect to action, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The overload for Html.ActionLink is:

```
Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controller", object routeValues, object HtmlAttributes)
```

From what you've said, `mydirectory` = controller, and `List` = action, correct? If so, try:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(galleryImage.AnimalName, "List", "mydirectory", new { @id = galleryImage.AnimalName }, null) %>
```

this should produce:

```
<a href="/mydirectory/list/quack">quack</a>
```